# How to select id using email verification

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I need a query, so before entering into question I will introduce the database design

```
 Table Name- jom_community_users

 id || name || username || email || password || usertype || block || sendEmail  
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 799   aaaa    aaaa.bbbb  a@a.com   xxttxyyb   Registered     1          0  
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 800   xxxx    xxxx.yyyy  x@x.com   aabbxtta   Registered     1          0       

 Table Name- jom_community_invit

 from_id || to_email || point_given
 -----------------------------------
 799       x@x.com         1
```

select id from jom_community_users

- where email in this table is equal to to_email in jom_community_invit table
- points given should be one in jom_community_invit table

Comment: You can use join, refer this links http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html  http://mysqljoin.com/joins/inner-join-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are after but:

```
SELECT CU.id
FROM jom_community_users CU,jom_community_invit CI
WHERE CU.email = CI.to_email
AND CI.point_given = 1
```

As mentioned, I hope this is what you are asking for.

Comment: $query = 'SELECT '. $db->nameQuote(CU.'id')
               .' FROM '. $db->nameQuote('#__users'), $db->nameQuote('#__community_cinvited' CI)
            .' WHERE '. $db->nameQuote(CU.'email').'='.$db->Quote(CI.'to_email')
   .'AND'. $db->nameQuote(CI.'point_given').'='.$db->Quote('1');   any error in writing like this

Comment: i think it may be wrong here nameQuote('#__community_cinvited' CI) can i write CI like this

Comment: Ehm, I guess something like:

$query = 'SELECT CU.id
FROM jom_community_users CU,jom_community_invit CI
WHERE CU.email ='.$db->nameQuote(CU.'email').'
AND CI.to_email = CU.email
AND CI.point_given = 1'

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
$query = 'SELECT cu.id FROM #__community_users cu , #__community_invit ci
    WHERE cu.email = ci.to_email AND ci.point_given = 1';

//OR

$query = "SELECT cu.id FROM #__community_users cu JOIN #__community_invit ci
    ON(cu.email = ci.to_email AND ci.point_given='1')
    WHERE cu.email = ".$db->Quote($yourEmail);

$db->setQuery( $query );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM #_community_users a
INNER JOIN #_community_invit b
ON  a.email = b.to_email where b.point_given=1
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
Select id
from jom_community_users, jom_community_invit
where jom_community_users.email = jom_community_invit.to_email
and jom_community_invit.pont_given = 1
```